# loop each element and perform its own action and then store it in list<String>

Tags: java

I want to loop each element in the list. Within each element we still have actions for it, I wanted to implement these actions and then store it in a list form.

```
List<String> Str = words.stream().forEach(x->x.getSentenceStr().toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I received an error when trying to use my method:

cannot invoke collect on primitive type void.

I thought the forEach is use to loop each element in the list and if I perform certain action within each element, it will then return back the output while still looping it? Lastly, the collect will then collect all these output and convert it to list of string. Am I having the wrong understanding of this forEach function?

Here is my dummy trial:

```
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b", "c"));
    List<String> ss = s.stream().forEach(x->x.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` is meant to be used when all transformations have been done, and is `void`.

Comment: I see. thank you so much sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` is `void`, you need a **`map`** like

```
List<String> ss = s.stream().map(x -> x.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and you could use the shorter functional invocation of `String.toLowerCase()` like

```
List<String> ss = s.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sir, I actually wanted to know. Is it possible to use your shorter functional to be something like this? .map(String::getSentenceStr,toLowerCase) because before lowering it to lowercase I wanted to get the sentenceStr first. Is this possible?

Comment: yes like this `List<String> ss = s.stream().map(x->x.getSentenceStr()).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: thank you. So basically, I just have to split it to two maps one for action and another for conversion.

Comment: `String` doesn't have a method called `getSentenceStr()` so I'm a little confused about that, but you can define your own function and pass it to `map` and perform multiple transforms in one step (or invoke two `map`(s) in succession).